# C parser program to add/sub/div/mul. Reading input from user want to terminate my program on semicolon instead of pressing enter

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I have written C program that will read using read() user input for e.g:

`add 1 2 3
Result: 6`

Now the thing is, read will stop the read once enter is pressed. What if I want to terminate using any other character other than pressing an enter?
For e.g:

`add 1 2 3;
Result: 6`

Note--> As I press ; the read should stop reading and result should be displayed.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
while(1) {
char buff[50];
int rcount = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 50); //Reading user input
//write(1, buff, rcount);
buff[rcount - 1] = '\0'; //Converting user input as a string(char array)

/*If nothing is given and user press enter*/
if(strcasecmp(buff, "") == 0) {
    write(1, "Invalid argument\n", sizeof("Invalid argument\n"));
}

/*Getting the first argument*/
char *arr = strtok(buff, " ");

if(strcasecmp(arr, "exit") == 0) {
    break; //Break out of loop when exit is typed in
}
if(strcasecmp(arr, "add") == 0) {
    add(arr); //When first arg is add, call to add func
}
else if(strcasecmp(arr, "sub") == 0) {
    subtract(arr); //When first arg is sub, call to sub func
}
else if(strcasecmp(arr, "mul") == 0) {
    multiply(arr); //When first arg is mul, call to mul func
}
else if(strcasecmp(arr, "div") == 0) {
    divide(arr); //When first arg is div, call to div func
}
/*When first argument is anything else*/
else {
       write(1, "Invalid argument\n", sizeof("Invalid argument\n"));
}

printf("\n");


}
}

void add(char *arr) { //To add numbers --> args > 1

int sum = 0;
while(arr != NULL) { //Loop to get all the numbers and using them to   perform task
    //printf("%s\n", arr);
    int a = atoi(arr); //Converting arg/number to int
    sum += a;
    arr = strtok(NULL, " \n;");
}
char w[50];
int count = sprintf(w, "Result: %d\n", sum); //to use 'write', need to store sum as result so using sprintf instead of printf. Guess we've got no other option? 
write(1, w, count);
return;
}

void subtract(char *arr) { //To subtract numbers --> args > 1

    arr = strtok(NULL, " \n"); //To move to second arg
int subt = (int) atoi(arr); //to get the first number/2nd arg, as we will subtract remaining nums from this

arr = strtok(NULL, " \n"); //To move to remaining numbers, args > 2
    while (arr != NULL) {
    //printf("%s\n", arr);
        int a = atoi(arr);
        subt = subt - a;
        arr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

char w[50];
int count=sprintf(w, "Result: %d\n", subt);
write(1, w, count);
return;
}

void multiply(char *arr) { //To multiply numbers --> args > 1

int mult = 1;
arr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
while (arr != NULL) {
//printf("%s\n", arr);
    int a = atoi(arr);
    mult = mult * a;
    arr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
}
char w[50];
int count=sprintf(w, "Result: %d\n", mult);
write(1, w, count);
return;
}

void divide(char *arr) { //To divide numbers --> args > 1

arr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
float div = (float) atoi(arr);
//printf("%f", div);
//printf("\n");
arr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    while (arr != NULL) {
    //printf("%s\n", arr);
        float a = (float) atoi(arr);
        div = div / a;
        arr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

char w[50];
int count=sprintf(w, "Result: %f\n", div);
write(1, w, count);
return;
}
```

Comment: On Unix, you're getting into 'raw mode' input from your terminal, which is moderately fraught — be cautious.  For the most part, you should assume that the input lines will be terminated by a newline.  You can use semicolons as an intermediate separator, so you could have `add 1 2 3; sub 2 4; div 9 4` all on a single line.

Comment: Oh yea I forgot, it's for linux.

Comment: Your program won't see any input before the user presses enter, so no. And please do NOT do anything with ncurses. Terminal line editing exists for a reason. Don't mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might help, you can pass whatever terminating character into it as you please:

```
int add(char *str, char term)
{
    int res = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        while (*str && !isdigit(*str))
             str++;
        if (*str && isdigit(*str))
             res += atoi(*str);
        if (*str == term)
             break ;
        while (*str && isdigit(*str))
             str++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The main issue is getting the read to return when a semicolon is typed. The parsing part is easy.

Comment: This is skipping the issue of reading the data when the semicolon is pressed.  Once you've got the string, what you're doing is more or less right, but the question is more, I think, about how to get the input without hitting return.

Answer (score 0):

try man ncurses for more information, but this should work on most unixes:

```
  cc g.c -lncurses
  ./a.out
  cat g.c:  
    #include <ncurses.h>
    void main(void) {
        initscr();
        cbreak();
        while (getch() != ';') {
        }
        nocbreak();
        endwin();
    }
```